# Deforming a series of roof tiles to fit roof's geometry?

Tags: path

Here's the situation I have — there's a roof tile geometry (a beveled path) that I'm trying to get to fit the shape of the roof.

[image]

This is an array here, which is working well; the bump I'm running into is adjusting the shape to fit angled areas, e.g. the triangle shapes on the edge of the roof.

There's a lot of roof space beyond this that would need the tile — and I'm wondering how to fit this "tile" to the shape of the roof. Ideally in some way that would let me continue to refine the path as time goes on.

It seems like there might be good ways to do this short of converting it all to a mesh and making it fit by brute force — that, as a Blender newbie, I'm not yet aware of.

Thank you!

Comment: I couldn't get your issue: what you did, what you got, and why it doesn't work, sorry...

Comment: Look into Tissue Addon: http://www.co-de-it.com/wordpress/code/blender-tissue. It lets you tile a mesh piece (ie. a roof tile) by guiding surface, that you can easily adjust for the shape you need.

Comment: You're trying to shingle a roof? Unless you need some super close-ups I'd say do this with a bump texture. If you do need more "3D-ness" than that, try a particle system, but the particles will still collide at the corners and require special attention.